# Yii2 to heroku step by step but gives Forbidden error

Tags: heroku, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

Here is step by step what we have done.

- installed yii-advanced on my localhost (development mode)
- installed yii2-heroku extension from [offical yii extension section](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-heroku)
  by command:

  ```
  composer require --dev --prefer-dist purrweb/yii2-heroku "*"
  ```
- prepared Yii2 to production mode by command:

  ```
  php /path/to/yii-application/init --env=Production --overwrite=All
  ```
- tested localhost, and everything was great
- connected heroku dashboard and created a database (postgresql)
- migrated yii
- tested localhost, and database connection was ok
- connected heroku from terminal (heroku login)
- created an app on heroku
- created git for the local files
- and deployed files to heroku by command:

  ```
  git push heroku master
  ```
- tested and everything seems fine on heroku

but when I navigate to the my heroku app URL it says:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I have tried adding `frontend/web/index.php` to end of URL, but nothing changed except:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /frontend/web/index.php was not found on this
>   server.

So got stuck in that stage, How to proceed?

Comment: Are you setting the document root to /frontend/web?  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have solved the problem; made a mistake when install heroku extension, now everything is ok. Thanks